# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use `<%= f.email_field :email, value: current_user.email %>` in an html.erb file. Why do I get the error

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Could it be because I'm in a different controller? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is stating that `current_user` is nil - that is, no user is currently logged in.

If you want your view to work when no one is logged in, you could use `current_user.try(:email)`.